# How do you pass an argument to the Google Apps Script debugger?

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Say I have the following broken example function in a google-apps script.  The function is intended to be called from a google sheet with a string argument:

```
function myFunction(input) {
  var caps = input.toUpperCase()
  var output = caps.substrin(1, 4)
  return output
}
```

While this example script should break on line 3 when you select myFunction and press debug, as there is no such method as "substrin()," it will break on line 2, because you can't put undefined in all caps:

> TypeError: Cannot call method "toUpperCase" of undefined. (line 2,
>   file "Code")

**Question:**
Is there an official way to pass a string to a google-apps script for testing/debugging without making an additional function

```
function myOtherFunction() {
 myFunction("testString")
}
```

and debugging that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The function as you wrote it does need a parameter and there is no way to avoid that except by including a default value in the function itself. See example below

```
function myFunction(input) {
  input= input||'test';
  var caps = input.toUpperCase();
  var output = caps.substrin(1, 4);
  return output;
}
```

Comment: So this will choose 'test' if input starts as undefined, but otherwise use the input?  How does it decide which to use?  And there's no Google UI for this?

Comment: Yes. Add a Logger.log(output) before return to be able to visualize the output

Comment: input = input || 'test' is shorthand for
if ( !input ) input = 'test';
the logical or ("||") converts input to true or false, and if false, chooses the second operand.
Note, however, that 0 will evaluate to false, so if 0 is passed, input will be 'test'.
You can avoid this by using:
input = (input !== undefined) ? input : 'test';
On the other hand, *any* string will test as true:
("","0","false","undefined") will all evaluate to true.